# Having trouble with "make" while installing R-3.3.2 in Ubuntu command line

Tags: r, ubuntu, makefile

```
$ wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.2.tar.gz
$ tar xf R-3.3.2.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.3.2
$ ./configure
$ make 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

There aren't any normal makefiles in the R directory, just `Makeconf.in`, `Makefile.in`, and `Makefile.fw`. Is there some way to update make to handle these files?

Comment: `./configure` should have generated a lot of output, terminating in a section saying `R is now configured for...`. If `./configure` produced no output, then you might investigate `head ./configure` and verify that this looks like a shell script starting with `#! /bin/sh`.

Comment: What is the output if you do `sh -x ./configure`?

Comment: Okay, so far I've installed the compiler: `$ sudo apt-get install gfortran build-essential fort77 xorg-dev liblzma-dev  libblas-dev gcc-multilib gobjc++ aptitude libreadline-dev` and now I get the error: `checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error:bzip2 library and headers are required`